# display a solidworks drawing in a windows form

Tags: c#, api, solidworks

I need to load a Solidworks .slddrw drawing in to Visual Studio (C#) on a Windows Form. I then need to rotate this image using pitch/roll data. I would first just like to display the drawing. Does anyone know how to do this using the SolidWorks API?

Here is the code

```
public SolidWorksDrawing() 
{ 
   InitializeComponent(); 
   myGraphic = groupBox1.CreateGraphics(); 
   drawingFile = "C:\\BrendaDocs\\trunk_July10\\foodprocessor.slddrw"; 

   //ModelDoc2 swModel = default(ModelDoc2); 
   ModelDoc2 swModel = new ModelDoc2(); //class not registered 
}
```

I get "obj ref not set to an instance of an obj" on this line

```
swModel = default(ModelDoc2)
```

I get "Class not registered" on this line

```
swModel = new ModelDoc2()
```

I have a group box on a windows form and I am just trying to load and display the solidworks drawing for now

Comment: Six years later, this will not help, but you should be looking for the eModelView control - part of eDrawings.  I'm trying to figure that one out for myself and will try to post back here if I manage to build a working example.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this stuff in a few years but there was an edrawings control (activex?) which you could use. Edrawings is free solidworks viewer made by solidworks and then you can tell it what to do using the api. It would be ugly though.